# How do I detect if a string contains either a number as a digit or written as letters in C#?

Tags: c#, string, digits

I want to be able to detect whether a string contains a number, either written as a digit (0-9) or as letters in plain English (one, two, three..). The lettered numbers in the string should be detected as individual words, not parts of words.

So for example:

```
"This string contains no numbers" = false;
"This string contains the number 1" = true;
"This string contains the number three" = true;
"This string contains a dogs bone" = false; //contains the word 'one' as part of the word 'bone', therefore returns false
```

Couldn't find anything on SO that specifically answers this question; they're mostly to do with extracting just integers from strings so thought I'd go ahead and ask.

Is there a library that can handle this sort of stuff? If not, how can I approach this? Is there a faster way than putting all worded numbers into an array?

Comment: I didn't down vote you, but as per the "How do I ask a good question?" http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask article, you haven't shown what you've already researched and/or tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by simply you mean using a built in library then I'm not aware of one, I'll be gladly corrected if someone knows better.

**Edit: updated with OPs clarification and [AndyJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40631190/how-do-i-detect-if-a-string-contains-either-a-number-as-a-digit-or-written-as-le/40631315#comment68495950_40631315)'s recommendation**

To do this on separate words you can use this method instead:

```
public bool ContainsNumber(string s)
{
    // This is the 'filter' of things you want to check for
    // The '...' is for brevity, obviously it should have the other numbers here
    var numbers = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3", ... , "one", "two", "three" };

    // Split the provided string into words
    var words = s.Split(' ').ToList();

    // Checks if the list of words matches ANY of the provided numbers
    // Case and culture insensitive for better matching
    return words.Any(w => numbers.Any(n => n.Equals(w, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
}
```

Usage:

> ContainsNumber("No numbers here");
>   ContainsNumber("The number three");
>   ContainsNumber("The dog ate a bone");

Output:

> false
>   true
>   false

**Edit 2: To return matching words**

```
public List<string> GetMatches(string s)
{
    var numbers = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3", ... , "one", "two", "three" };
    var words = s.Split(' ').ToList();

    return words.Intersect(numbers, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).ToList();
}
```

Usage:

> GetMatches("this has no numbers");
>   GetMatches("this has one number");
>   GetMatches("this 1 has a bone");
>   GetMatches("1 two 3 and then some more");

Output:

> null
>   "one"
>   "1"
>   "1", "two", "3"

Comment: Well yes, it would return true for the sentence, but it's correct. The string **does** contain a number.

Comment: It's unclear what OP wanted so thought I'd mention this particular edge case.

Comment: @Poody ... Spoken like a true programmer ;) though I suspect the OP meant "as individual words".

Comment: I think that your second approach is the best, because it removes the problem with words which contains numbers.

Comment: If/when OP clarifies what he wants I can remove the offending method, I'll leave both for posterity for now.

Comment: A slight tweak would make it case and culture insensitive ... return words.Any(w => numbers.Any(n => n.Equals(w, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));

Comment: @AndyJ Hadn't considered culture and forgot case, have added this in. Thanks!

Comment: Even though my question is getting slain with downvotes, I have edited it for further clarity. I am an amateur programmer and wasn't sure how to approach this problem, so in return for trying to find out how to approach, I get nailed with downvotes. Way to go to help boost the confidence of somebody wanting to find out more.

Comment: Don't let it bother you. For the record I didn't vote. Thanks for the clarification, will tidy up my answer. Let me know if it has problems.

Comment: I appreciate your time and effort; seems like the best solution so far. If nothing better surfaces, then I will accept yours! 

I'll try not to let it bother me, it's just really frustrating when I ask a perfectly reasonable question (baring in mine there are FAR worse and unclear questions out there) and it gets bombarded with negativity.

Comment: @blueprintChris You don't have to be a pro to use google :/ You don't even have to know how to use google ... you can google "how do I use google?". I suspect in this case if you did use google you wouldn't find any decent results. However that's a perfectly bit of research to document. "I tired to google for X, Y, and Z, but I only found A and B which didn't help". The question itself is reasonable, but the way you asked it implies you don't care enough to put effort in. The article I linked to before says "Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague".

Comment: I did google for results but found nothing - I assumed that was a given due to me creating my own question?

Comment: @AndyJ - I have edited my question. Apart from the mind-blowingly obvious facts, is there anything else I need to put in there to not get maimed?

Comment: As you yourself said, there's a lot of bad and low effort questions out there. Again, back to the article I linked. "Even if you don't find a useful answer elsewhere on the site, including links to related questions that haven't helped can help others in understanding how your question is different from the rest.". Think of that article as describing the etiquette expected on SO.

Comment: I can only see that people would have down-voted because it didn't clearly show effort. As you've explained it's not always possible, especially if you're a beginner. Can only recommend taking it on the chin and moving on, tomorrow you'll ask a question with 5 up-votes and make more rep than you lost. Also, please don't argue further in comments, take it to chat ;-)

Comment: @Equalsk how would I go about returning said worded numbers from a string?

Comment: I've added an example for Intersect.

Comment: Thank you, really helped me out. I'm fairly new to C# so it's the first time I've seen the Intersect function

Answer (score 0):

create an array with everything you want to look in that string and iterate on it.

its the fasted solution if you only care about single digits. if you want to do it with all kind of numbers, it will require some more work.....

Comment: it's about 4-5 lines of code. it more for homework purpose, not from real life development. you can make an array for the strings and run a for loop for the numbers... but its the same idea.

Comment: @Equalsk just implement this idea. 5 lines :-)